# Searching for a keyword in PDF using iTextSharp 7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I am trying to search for a keyword within PDF file using C# and iTextSharp.

So I have come across this piece of code:

```
public List<int> ReadPdfFile(string fileName, String searthText)
        {
            List<int> pages = new List<int>();
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            { 
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
                for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

                    string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
                    if (currentPageText.Contains(searthText))
                    {
                        pages.Add(page);
                    }
                }
                pdfReader.Close();
            }
            return pages;
        }
```

But it says that PdfReader does not contain the definition for NumberOfPages. Is there any other way I can get number of pages in PDF file?

Comment: Check this using pdf clown https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56162692/read-specific-value-based-on-label-name-from-pdf-in-c-sharp/57999452#57999452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The piece of code you found is for iText 5.5.x. iText 7 has a fundamentally changed API, so your `NumberOfPages` problem is not the only problem you'll have to deal with.

Nonetheless: To get the number of pages in iText 7, you now use the `PdfDocument` method `GetNumberOfPages` instead of the former `PdfReader` property `NumberOfPages`.

And more generally, a port of your method to iText 7 might look like this:

```
public List<int> ReadPdfFile(string fileName, String searthText)
{
    List<int> pages = new List<int>();
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName))
        using (PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader))
        {
            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

                string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDocument.GetPage(page), strategy);
                if (currentPageText.Contains(searthText))
                {
                    pages.Add(page);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return pages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this

```
pdfReader.NumberOfPages
```

by

```
getNumberOfPdfPages(fileName)
```

And the method ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320281/determine-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-file)) :

```
public int getNumberOfPdfPages(string fileName)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(fileName)))
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"/Type\s*/Page[^s]");
        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(sr.ReadToEnd());

        return matches.Count;
    }
}
```

But it seems weird that the NumberOfPages is not recognized... Are your sure about your `using` ?

Comment: Thank you! Well this is what i am using : ``` using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser; using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener; using iText.Kernel.Pdf; using iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Filter; using iText.Pdfa; using iText.Signatures; ```
I also have a problem with: `string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);` For all 3 arguments it states that it can't convert it from one type to another...